# TextField & BLoC : pre-filling a field

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield, bloc

I have a screen with a form that I use to post an ad and I use that same screen to edit an ad. When I want to edit an ad, the form is pre-fill with the content of the ad. I do that by giving the text to display to a `TextEditingController`.

At the same time, I use the BLoC pattern to manage the business logic of my app, and I yield a new state in the `onChange` property of the `Textfield`. Because of that, the textfield is built at every single change and as a result, the `TextEditingController` is also built preventing me from changing the text of the field.

```dart
 TextField(
      controller: isUpdate ? 
        TextEditingController(
          text: isUpdate == true ? myAd.property.toString() //as it builds at every single change, the text can't be modified 
            : null,
        ): null,
      onChanged: (newValue) {
         context.read<MyBloc>().add(TitleChanged(value: newValue))
```

So is there a way for me to pre-fill the field, but only once -not at every single build-, so that I can continue to edit it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the code to use **`TextFormField`** and set **`initialValue`**

```
 TextFormField(
      initialValue: isUpdate ? myAd.property.toString(): null,
      onChanged: (newValue) {
         context.read<MyBloc>().add(TitleChanged(value: newValue))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could include the Text as a String in your Blocs state so instead of using `myAd.property.toString()` you use `state.formText`.
Anytime you change the form using your `TitleChanged`event, you also update the `formText` in your bloc.